# Webpart integration in Application page

Tags: web-part, branding

I exported the List as webpart using Sharepoint Designer for "News and Annoucements". I have created a custom login page for our web app (application page). Is it possible to integrate the webpart with the login page.

Thanks

Manny

Answer (score 1):

Technically, what you exported was a webpart file (either .dwp or .webpart) and it is just an XML file that contains the information SharePoint needs to present the underlying content but it does not include the content itself.  As such, whether or not you can incorporate it in a login page depends entirely on your site security.

If your "News and Announcements" list is only visible to authenticated users then no, you cannot include it on the login page as the user has not yet authenticated.  However, if you grant anonymous the permission to read that list, then you should be able to use the webpart on the login page.

Comment: Hi Dave, We have enabled anonymous access and have set IUSR account with read permissions to the list. How can I set permission on the Webpart? also,could you please recommend any article which can help me with integration.

Comment: You cannot set permissions on a webpart as all related security is controlled either by the page containing the webpart or by the content that the webpart points to.  An easy way to check is past the URL to the list in your browser and attempt to view it without logging in.  If you can't see it, then your Site and List permissions still need adjusting.  Also, enabling anonymous access is a little more involved in SharePoint than you might think : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/enable-anonymous-access-HA010113018.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add list view xslt webpart in application page.

please see this link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/983d2098-d742-4708-8bdc-437aa07b3b9d/

you telling about login page so it's depends on permissions on list if your list has anonymous access only for view then u just display list data not insert or update ......